# How to solve out the family - inter relations project

Tags: c, data-structures

Currently we have been assigned the project related to family relationships systems. We have to input data in the form of `NAME1 RELATION NAME2` and for each instance of our input we have to analyse the gender of `NAME1` from the `RELATION` it has with the other member.

Now that's not the problem we are facing. Currently we are facing the trouble to solving inter family relationships, let's suppose this data is entered :

```
A FATHER B
B BROTHER C
```

Now from here I want to make the computer identify the relationships between 
A and C. I was thinking of doing it with a linear search but our instructor believes that it will be a very slow process in searching it linearly and thus advises us to do it using binary search or hash table.

Can anybody please help us on how to solve this out?

You can see all of the work I have done.https://github.com/Jorker22/project

Answer (score 0):

Allocate an array for each person, every index will represent a relation , like `index 0 = MOTHER`, `index 1 = FATHER`, `index 3 = SON`, and insert the connection in the right index.

You will be able binary searching with the right indexing.

**Example** array a for A: `a[FATHER]=B,a[UNCLE]=C` array b for B: `b[BROTHER]=C.`

With some helping functions you need to update `C` as ***UNCLE*** when `b[BROTHER]=C` added.

Comment: Thank you very much.i will follow your instruction.